# Creating a poor man's DNS/name resolution with VirtualBox NAT network

Tags: virtualbox, dns, nat

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.22 on Windows 10 Pro (`mikaw10`) as host and have set up the following systems all with one NIC and a NAT network called `unix-machines`:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit (`ubuntu1404`)
- FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE 32 bit (`bsd9`)
- FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE 64 bit (`bsd10`)

All VMs receive their IPs via DHCP from the NAT network. While this runs fine, I cannot get a simple name resolution. Reading several questions on superuser.com, I have added the NAT IP of my host along with its host name and the IPs of the VMs and their names to the `hosts` on Windows. Enabled `natdnsproxy1` and `natdnshostresolver1` from [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat), but doing a simple `ping <hostname>` does not work. Supplying IPs only make it instantly work.

How can I make it work without tampering `/etc/hosts` on all VMs without creating a special VM just for DNS (zone `local`)?

Comment: I think it does not work as your host's DNS does not know about your VMs (it might with a bridged connection). So no simple solution. Just the two you mentioned (editing hosts files or setting up a DNS for your NATed unix-machines network.

Comment: @Zina Are you certain? My host is able to resolve those names due to its local `hosts` file. I assumed the `natdnshostresolver1` is supposed to use it.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. From the Manual you linked `9.11.6. Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode

For resolving network names, the DHCP server of the NAT engine offers a list of registered DNS servers of the host. If for some reason you need to hide this DNS server list and use the host's resolver settings, thereby forcing the VirtualBox NAT engine to intercept DNS requests and forward them to host's resolver` - which means that with this setting your VM will use the DNS from your host (not your host's host file!!!)

Comment: @Zina, exactly. Therefore, I have set the options and expected that VirtualBox would use the host's C API to resolve hosts. Intercepting all traffic to `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Hm, okay. I understood it like it will forward it to the nameservers in the hosts resolv.conf. As it does not work for you, you should setup wireshark on your host to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea but I won't see any `fopen` to the `hosts` file on Windows. It won't help me much. Will it? I think, if VirtuaBox logs this, this should be displayed in the log files.